# Complicated multirow/column table

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow

Hopefully this is the last of my table questions.

I have never done a table like this before and I'm not sure how to set it up with multirow/column (i'm assuming there is no easier way).

Here is the code I have so far (I did not put the actual numbers in yet). I've been trying to use booktabs.

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow, array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{3}[2]{*}{1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{4}[4]{*}{2}} & \multirow{3}[2]{*}{3} \\
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &  \\
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &  \\
\cmidrule{1-3}\cmidrule{7-7}    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{4} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & 5 \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{6} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{7} & 8 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
 \end{center}

\end{document}
```

This is what the table looks like now:

[image]

and this is what it eventually needs to look like:

[image]

I've been using arrays instead of tabular for other tables but this one seems a bit too complicated to go that route.

Please help as I need to write several tables like this but with different orders (ie: the last row of the table will eventually need to be at the top). 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this type of table, you do not need some of the styles you are loading.

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{multirow, array,arydshln}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
     & &  \\
    1 & & 3 \\
     & &  \\
    \cdashline{1-1} \cdashline{3-3} 
    4 &\multirow{-4}{*}{2} & 5\\ 
    \hline
    6 & 7 & 8\\ 
    \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\[
 \begin{array}{|>{\centering\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|c|}
    \hline
     & &  \\
    A & & b \\
     & &  \\
    \cdashline{1-1} \cdashline{3-3} 
    \bar c &\multirow{-4}{*}{$I_{(m+1)}$} & d\\ 
    \hline
    \bar 0_n & \bar 0_{(m+1)} & 0\\ 
    \hline
 \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to get the 0s in the first row, you only need to move the row up in the TeX code.

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\[
 \begin{array}{|>{\centering\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|c|}
    \hline
    \bar 0_n & \bar 0_{(m+1)} & 0\\ 
    \hline
     & &  \\
    A & & b \\
     & &  \\
    \cdashline{1-1} \cdashline{3-3} 
    \bar c &\multirow{-4}{*}{$I_{(m+1)}$} & d\\ 
    \hline
 \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! When moving rows (say the last row of 0's needs to appear at the top) does {|>{\centering\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|c|} need to change?

Comment: @ErikaOlsen No. You can move the row up. `\centering` means that the cell content is centered, the argument of `p` is the width, and the `\bigstrut` gives the cells a bit padding.

Comment: Thanks!! You're awesome!

Comment: @ErikaOlsen I cannot tell you what you are doing wrong because I do not know what you are doing but I just added a version with the 0s in the first line. (Will now be offline for a bit.)

Comment: What do the & & do? haha sorry about my last comment